# How do I update Safari on Windows?

Tags: windows, security, safari

I'd like to update Safari to 4.0.5 for security reasons, but I can't figure out how to run the Apple updater manually. On Mac there's usually a "Check for Updates" menu item, but I don't see one on the Windows version. I tried downloading the latest version from http://www.apple.com/safari/download/, but Windows won't let me open the file, saying it is a security risk.

Comment: Interresting... Check what's the error message because I can download it here. Can you paste your error message?

Comment: Wow, lucky you to have such a problem. I can't get that damn Apple update software to stop running.  :-)

Comment: The security problem was that I had my Internet security settings set to "High." Taking them down to "Medium-High" while I downloaded the file worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There will be a software, namely, [Apple Software Update](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Software_Update) . Check thoroughly in the Programs.

[image]

Comment: Aha! It's a top-level item under Programs. I assumed it would be in the Safari folder.

Comment: there's no other way to update..?  ...... way to go apple, I'm still waiting on them to come out with a new whole house security system with a doorknob that you can only use if you buy a MacBook...

Comment: @SgtPooki - What's so bad about that method of updating?  Seems pretty straightforward to me.

Comment: @jahroy, yea I guess. It seems kind of lazy not to at least provide some way of updating an app within that app. I mean, they do allow you to update within the app on a mac right.. soo.. why not on windows? I've got a sour taste in my mouth regarding all things apple because they just seem to act 'uppity'. That's the only way I can explain it.

Comment: and sure, it is lazy to not leave the app to run the update program, but aren't you supposed to make things easier on your users?

Comment: @SgtPooki - I believe Safari can only be updated via Software Update on a Mac as well (tho I can't confirm that at the moment).  It's probably becuase Safari is so integrated into the OS (just like IE on Windows).  I don't ever touch IE, but doesn't it update on Windows the **exact** same way as Safari on Mac?  When I google "_update IE_" [this page](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/update-internet-explorer) says to run "_Windows Update_".